# Fill in missing week of daily data using a different dataset's weekly data

Tags: pyspark

I have 2 datasets with dates and number of visitors for cities. One of the datasets is supposed to have daily data, but is missing some dates info. The other has all dates, but at a weekly lvl combined, and always on a Saturday (see below).

Dataset A:

```
City     |      Date         |        visitors
A        |       9/1/22      |         10
A        |       9/2/22      |         12
A        |       9/3/22      |         20
A        |       9/4/22      |         0
A        |       9/5/22      |         0
A        |       9/6/22      |         0
A        |       9/7/22      |         0
A        |       9/8/22      |         0
A        |       9/9/22      |         0
A        |       9/10/22     |         0
A        |       9/11/22     |         19
```

Dataset B:

```
City     |      Date          |        visitors_weekly
A        |       9/3/22       |         30
A        |       9/10/22      |         50
A        |       9/17/22      |         25
```

What I want to do is fill in Dataset A with rows from Dataset B if A is missing 7d of data in a row from a Sunday through Saturday. In those cases, take the corresponding Saturday from dataset B, divide it by 7, and fill in those rows for the week in dataset A. So in the example above dataset A would become:

```
City     |      Date         |        visitors
A        |       9/1/22      |         10
A        |       9/2/22      |         12
A        |       9/3/22      |         20
A        |       9/4/22      |         7.143
A        |       9/5/22      |         7.143
A        |       9/6/22      |         7.143
A        |       9/7/22      |         7.143
A        |       9/8/22      |         7.143
A        |       9/9/22      |         7.143
A        |       9/10/22     |         7.143
A        |       9/11/22     |         19
```

This is the current way Im doing it, but is there a better/more efficient way to do it?

```
# step 1: find the week of the year we're in, factoring in when we loop into next year (the otherwise condition)
# We only deal with data 365d out maximum
# adj_weekOfYear adjusts it so that we start with today as the first week of the year instead of Jan
adj_weekOfYear = F.weekofyear(F.col("date")+1) - F.weekofyear(F.current_date()+1)
dataset_A = dataset_A.withColumn(
    "week_of_year",
    F.when(
        (adj_weekOfYear >= 0) & (F.year(F.col("date")) == F.year(F.current_date())),
        adj_weekOfYear
    ).otherwise(adj_weekOfYear + 52)
)

dataset_B = dataset_B.withColumn(
    "week_of_year",
    F.when(
        (adj_weekOfYear >= 0) & (F.year(F.col("date")) == F.year(F.current_date())),
        adj_weekOfYear
    ).otherwise(adj_weekOfYear + 52)
)

df = dataset_A.join(
    dataset_B.drop("date"),
    [“city”, "week_of_year"],
    'left'
).withColumn(
    # in dataset A, if weeks_daily_visitors is null then we can tell we're missing that week's info
    "weeks_daily_visitors”,
    F.sum(F.col("visitors”)).over(Window.partitionBy(“city”, “week_of_year"))
).withColumn(
    # edge case for beg and end of data, want to make sure we have a full week sun-sat before filling in with dataset B
    "num_rows_for_week",
    F.count("date").over(Window.partitionBy("city”, "week_of_year"))
).withColumn(
    "missing_weeks_daily_visitors",
    F.when(
        # if we dont have all 7 days of the week, cant fill in
        F.col("num_rows_for_week") < 7, F.lit("No")
    ).when(
        (F.col("weeks_daily_visitors").isNull() | (F.col("weeks_daily_visitors") < 1)),
        # if we're missing the week's data in A we should mark to fill in with B
        F.lit("Yes")
    ).otherwise(F.lit("No"))
).withColumn(
    "visitors",
    F.when(
        F.col("missing_weeks_daily_demand") == 'Yes',
        F.col("visitors_weekly") / 7
    ).otherwise(F.col("demand"))
)
```

So in the examples above it'd look like (if today was 9/1/22):

df

```
City  |  Date      |  visitors |  week of yr |  weeks_daily_visitors | visitors_weekly | num_rows_for_week | missing_weeks_daily_visitors
A     |  9/1/22    |  10       |  0          |  33                   | 30              | 3                 | No
A     |  9/2/22    |  12       |  0          |  33                   | 30              | 3                 | No
A     |  9/3/22    |  20       |  0          |  33                   | 30              | 3                 | No
A     |  9/4/22    |  0        |  1          |  0                    | 50              | 7                 | Yes
A     |  9/5/22    |  0        |  1          |  0                    | 50              | 7                 | Yes
A     |  9/6/22    |   0       |  1          |  0                    | 50              | 7                 | Yes
A     |  9/7/22    |  0        |  1          |  0                    | 50              | 7                 | Yes
A     |  9/8/22    |   0       |  1          |  0                    | 50              | 7                 | Yes
A     |  9/9/22    |   0       |  1          |  0                    | 50              | 7                 | Yes
A     |  9/10/22   |   0       |  1          |  0                    | 50              | 7                 | Yes
A     |  9/11/22   |  19       |  2          |  19                   | 25              | 1                 | No
```

And then the last step replaces the 0s for week of yr 1 with 7.143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the week-ending Saturday date for all the dates in the first dataframe which will make it easier to track the missing values by weeks and map it using the second dataframe which is at a week-ending Saturday date level.

Here's an attempt using your sample.

```py
data1_sdf. \
    withColumn('wk_saturday', func.expr('date_add(dt, 7 - dayofweek(dt))')). \
    withColumn('missing_visit', 
               func.sum((func.col('visit') == 0).cast('int')).over(wd.partitionBy('wk_saturday'))
               ). \
    alias('a'). \
    join(data2_sdf.alias('b'), 
         [func.col('a.city') == func.col('b.city'), 
          func.col('a.wk_saturday') == func.col('b.dt')], 
         'left'
         ). \
    drop(func.col('b.city')). \
    drop(func.col('b.dt')). \
    withColumn('updated_visit',
               func.when(func.col('missing_visit') == 7, func.col('visit_wk') / 7).
               otherwise(func.col('visit'))
               ). \
    show()

# +----+----------+-----+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+
# |city|        dt|visit|wk_saturday|missing_visit|visit_wk|    updated_visit|
# +----+----------+-----+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+
# |   A|2022-09-11|   19| 2022-09-17|            0|      25|             19.0|
# |   A|2022-09-04|    0| 2022-09-10|            7|      50|7.142857142857143|
# |   A|2022-09-05|    0| 2022-09-10|            7|      50|7.142857142857143|
# |   A|2022-09-06|    0| 2022-09-10|            7|      50|7.142857142857143|
# |   A|2022-09-07|    0| 2022-09-10|            7|      50|7.142857142857143|
# |   A|2022-09-08|    0| 2022-09-10|            7|      50|7.142857142857143|
# |   A|2022-09-09|    0| 2022-09-10|            7|      50|7.142857142857143|
# |   A|2022-09-10|    0| 2022-09-10|            7|      50|7.142857142857143|
# |   A|2022-09-01|   10| 2022-09-03|            0|      30|             10.0|
# |   A|2022-09-02|   12| 2022-09-03|            0|      30|             12.0|
# |   A|2022-09-03|   20| 2022-09-03|            0|      30|             20.0|
# +----+----------+-----+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a cleaner way to do the join you're looking for:

```
combined_df = (
    daily_df.join(
        weekly_df,
        daily_df.Date.between(F.date_add(weekly_df.Date, -6), weekly_df.Date),
        "left"
    )
    .select(
        daily_df.City,
        daily_df.Date,
        daily_df.Visitors,
        weekly_df.Visitors_Weekly
    )
    .withColumn("DailyVisitors_Adjusted",
        F.when(daily_df.Visitors == 0, weekly_df.Visitors_Weekly/7)
        .otherwise(daily_df.Visitors)
    )
)
```

The output:

```
+----+----------+--------+---------------+----------------------+
|City|      Date|Visitors|Visitors_Weekly|DailyVisitors_Adjusted|
+----+----------+--------+---------------+----------------------+
|   A|2022-09-01|      10|             30|                  10.0|
|   A|2022-09-02|      12|             30|                  12.0|
|   A|2022-09-03|      20|             30|                  20.0|
|   A|2022-09-04|       0|             50|     7.142857142857143|
|   A|2022-09-05|       0|             50|     7.142857142857143|
|   A|2022-09-06|       0|             50|     7.142857142857143|
|   A|2022-09-07|       0|             50|     7.142857142857143|
|   A|2022-09-08|       0|             50|     7.142857142857143|
|   A|2022-09-09|       0|             50|     7.142857142857143|
|   A|2022-09-10|       0|             50|     7.142857142857143|
|   A|2022-09-11|      19|             25|                  19.0|
+----+----------+--------+---------------+----------------------+
```

As to the other thing you mentioned in the code snippet about not filling it in if the week isn't complete in the daily table - I'd say the approach is different depending on how the data's structured and what you're trying to accomplish. For example, if you don't want to fill the daily table in with a weekly average if it's missing a day in the middle of it that would probably be different than if you get a new record every day and just want to wait to backfill with averages until all dates are there.